# Why all that mass didnt collapsed in on itself at the begining of 'big bang'(whatever it was)?

Tags: black-holes, big-bang, mass-energy, subatomic

[image]

Im not a physicist,but i love physics.I cant find an answer for this questions easily as an amateur.

If the big bang happened by itself in nothingness,why it doesnt happen in our space-time again and again in random places?

Comment: Please *type out* any questions you may want to ask rather than forcing us to decipher your handwriting.

Comment: There is a lot here. If I were to narrow in an answer to the central question it would be that the singularity associated with black holes is spacelike, or contained in a spacelike region, and the singularity of the big bang is timelike. Timelike singularities means from the geodesic incompleteness or beginning/end of a path there is a continuous path to the present without the obscuring properties of an event horizon. This is one reason that matter expanded, for inflationary pressures are associated with the timelike singularity.

Comment: @LawrenceB.Crowell Awesome answer,thank you!
Sorry for the handwriting.Wont happen again.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest answer is that we have a cosmological model which fits the observations we have up to now, and can predict new observations to be looked for, and up to now the model is validated, i.e. it is correct. It is the Big Bang model with [inflation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inflation_(cosmology)), which is whence you got your

> the big bang happened by itself in nothingness,

in the present model the question

> ,why it doesnt happen in our space-time again and again in random places?

is answered by the fact that the cosmological model in the places we can observe, the observable universe, has a [very small](https://cds.cern.ch/record/485959/files/0102033.pdf)  [cosmological constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmological_constant).

> the cosmological constant (usually denoted by the Greek capital letter lambda: Λ) is the value of the energy density of the vacuum of space.

The present big bang model posits that at the beginning of the universe,there was a large cosmological constant, i.e. large vacuum energy density. So conditions within our  observable universe do not allow for new universes to appear within it in random places.

We only have this one universe and our mathematical model tells us that the energy density was very high when our universe appeared, but how probable that was is a guess .

I cannot attempt to answer the handwritten part, partially because I cannot read it and also because it contains many questions.

Comment: Thanks for the awesome answer! I will dig into these topics.